# jquery add closed tag

Tags: jquery, append

I have a problem with jquery. After many tests, no simple solution for me.

My CMS return me this code

```
<ul>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
</ul>
```

I want add after each class=last this code

```
</ul><ul>
```

in order to obtain this code

```
<ul>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
</ul><ul>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
</ul><ul>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li class="last">text</li>
</ul>
```

I tried with jquery with this code

```
$('.last').after('</ul><ul>')
```

but impossible to append this text. I obtain

```
<ul></ul>
```

and not

```
</ul><ul>
```

Can you give me a solution for my problem. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't split a DOM node like that, you have to add a new `<ul></ul>` and move the relevant subnodes over to it.

On a side note, have you considered not splitting the list at all and instead decorating `.last` to look like a separator (empty space, which is what I'm assuming you're trying to achieve)?

Comment: Thanks for responses. I will try with another separator but my first idea is not to touch the code from my CMS.

Comment: Then the separator idea should be better than destructively manipulating the DOM at run-time. You'd have on your hands a brittle (upgrades could break it), non-degradable (turning js off would ruin your site) mess on your hands.

Comment: Yes. you're right, will be better. I'll try to work first in the cms to rewrite the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to code it right now, but I think you could use "detach":

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Detach the li elements and then add them to a new list and proceed to build your lists that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(I am assuming this ul lies in some container say div.

```
var container = $("div");
var ul = $("<ul/>");
var lis = $("ul > li", container);
container.empty();
lis.each(function(){

   ul.append(this);
   if($(this).hasClass("last")){
     container.append(ul);
     ul = $("<ul/>");
   }
});
container.append(ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of brute force but try this:

```
var newUL = [$('<ul></ul>')];    

$('ul.className li').each(function(i, el) {
   newUL[newUL.length - 1].append($(el));
   if($(el).hasClass('last')) {
      newUL.push($('<ul></ul>'));
   }
});
```

Once you're done, you can get the new html by saying:

```
$('#ulParent').empty.append(newUL.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks but i will first try to change the output from my cms (drupal). If not possible, i keep your solution.