# jQuery .after() tries to "correct" the html I'm inserting. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to break down a long unordered list into smaller pieces like this:

```
$('.cList').each(function() {
    var thisList = $(this).find('li')
    var thisLen = thisList.length
    for(var x=0;x<thisLen;x++) {
        if((x % 5)==0&&x>0) {
            $(thisList).eq(x).after("</ul><ul>")    
        }    
    }
})
```

What I end up with is this:

```
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<ul></ul> <---- I want the list to end and start, not make a nested list
```

instead of this:

```
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul><ul>  <--- like this
```

It's as if inserting `</ul><ul>` is not valid HTML and jQuery is somehow decidng that `<ul></ul>` is valid.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MGHt5/

Comment: When you ask jQuery to insert HTML, it creates a set of DOM element out of the given HTML, then inserts those DOM elements.  So, in your example, the `</ul>` is superfluous.  The `<ul>` results in a new list, and that is inserted into the DOM.  As such, if you want to break a list up, you're going to have to create a new list, remove the list items from the old list, add them to the new list, and the insert the new list after the current list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery split long ul list in smaller lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists)

Comment: The code in the duplicate worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of worrying specifically about open- and close-tags, I'd use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll) to wrap `<ul>` tags around a jQuery object containing 5 `<li>`s. You can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice) to grab chunks of `<li>`s from `thisList`.

Comment: $(thisList).eq(x).wrapAll("</ul><ul>")  creates a nested list after </li>

Comment: Did you mean `.wrapAll("<ul></ul>")`?

Comment: I ended up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists