# Adding </ul><ul> after every 5th <li> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, css-selectors

I have a list and I need to add `</ul><ul class="list">` after every 5th li so the list looks like this

```
    <ul>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a> </li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

and ends looking like this

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a> </li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
  <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

my current jQuery is not working because it is switching the order of the ul's

```
var ulVal = jQuery('</ul><ul class="links">');
jQuery('ul.col1 li:nth-child(5n)').after(ulVal)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by switching the order of the UL's?

Comment: I mean mine add the ul in this order `<ul class="list"></ul>` instead of the way I want it like this `</ul><ul class="list">`

Comment: @Ashlee Just for reference, jQuery is not actually switching the order of the opening and closing tags you pass it. Instead, you are [creating a new element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery). Try it out - remove the closing </ul> from that statement and you will notice that you still get exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The current state of the document is maintained by the browser as a tree of DOM objects representing nested elements and text nodes. It is **not** maintained as some HTML markup source that you can make arbitrary edits to, even if `after()` makes you think that's what it's doing.

So:

```
jQuery('</ul><ul class="links">');
```

This can't work. `jQuery(markup)` can only create DOM nodes from well-formed elements, starting with a start tag and including content and an end tag where necessary. It can't create an object representing an end-tag and the start-tag of a different element.

Instead of trying to work with HTML source, move the existing element nodes around in the DOM.

```
var items= ul.children();
for (var i= 0; i<items.length-5; i+= 5)
    items.slice(i, i+5).appendTo( $('<ul class="list">').insertBefore(ul) );
```

Comment: Implied is that you'll have selected your original `<ul>` element first through whatever means you are using to do it, eg `var ul= $('#mylist');`. If you have multiple list blocks you want to split independently, put `$('.mylist').each(function(){ ... });` around it and use `this` for `ul`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked here: [jQuery split long ul list in smaller lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists)

I modified the answer to do what you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
  var $bigList = $('.col1'), group;
  while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(5)').remove()).length){
    $('<ul class="links" />').append(group).appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

Depending on how exactly you are using this you will probably want to change the appendTo value to the location of the original list and then remove that now-empty list. Of course you can also tweak this to add column numbers (like your `col1`) to each group, etc.