# Adding elements into an li with jquery

Tags: jquery

If I have a ul with 10 li elements in it, with jQuery what would be the quickest and least intensive way of splitting that group of lis into three uls (still within the original ul) to end up with something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li>list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 5</li>
      <li>list item 6</li>
      <li>list item 7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 8</li>
      <li>list item 9</li>
      <li>list item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using .wrap but that seemed to be wrapping every element in the list (understandable, it's an array after all), I'm currently thinking that creating the new uls and injecting the existing lis into them.

Any thoughts are welcome, I've not used jQuery much before.
Thanks

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Use .each() to loop through each li, and then .prepend() and .append() to add ul tags in the right places.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists

Comment: if you split by three, where do the rest of the li's go if their number is not evenly divided by 3 ?

Comment: I can't share as it's a bit theoretical that I was messing with to learn more jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go.

http://jsfiddle.net/WqXnS/1/

*It creates a new list rather than replacing the original list simply for illustrative purposes.*

Comment: Thanks for that, Th0rndike above appears to have found a good duplicate that I didn't so I'm going with that just now.