# if li in ul has a class, put following li in new ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

i don't have access to some back-end stuff and i have no help. this is what i need to do, i need jquery code that will find the second class "text" and put it and the following li's in a new ul.

this

```
<ul>
  <li class="text">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="text">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul>
<li class="text">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="text">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
<li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried a bunch of code but cant get it to work, any suggestions?

Comment: First of all , you don't NEED from us, but you ask TO us. 
In Second istance what did you try? Do you know how to code in javascript/jquery ?

Comment: It's not a simple as it looks unfortunately.  My suggestion is to create a new set of `<ul></ul>` tags and move the `li.text` element and all subsequent li elements with it into the new list.  See also this related question about splitting a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists

Comment: is it possible to add custom class name? this is to make life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('ul').find('li.text').unwrap().each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.text').andSelf().wrapAll($('<ul/>'));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NScVe/)**

It doesn't matter how many li.text's are there and how many groups you need to create and doesn't leave elements unwrapped and abandoned with the help of chaining.

Answer (score 2):

This oughta do it:

```
$('li.text:first').nextUntil('li.text').addBack().wrapAll('<ul>');
$('li.text:eq(1)').nextAll().addBack().wrapAll('<ul>');
$('li.text:first').closest('ul').unwrap();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WuTUk/)**

Will produce:

```
<ul>
    <li class="text">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="text">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
    <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this was very helpful. thank you. you saved my wall a "forhead" shaped hole

Answer (score 0):

Something like `$("ul li")` will return all of the list items *in the order that they appear in the DOM*. You can then loop through them and as soon as you find the second one, just do something like:

```
$("li").before("</ul><ul>")
```

EDIT: Sorry, use `before()` not `prepend()`.

Answer (score 0):

look into [JQuery .wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
// do some checks
    $(".someclass").wrap("<ul></ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this using the most efficient way:

First, I add a custom class name (named 'first') to the first occurence of class 'text'.

```
<ul>
  <li class="text first">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="text">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
  <li class="subText">TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

Then, use jQuery function to find and replace the string to what we want:

```
var myHTMLcontent = $("ul").html();

var newContent=myHTMLcontent.replace('<li class="text">','</ul><ul><li class="text">');

$("ul").html(newContent);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul .text').eq(1).prev().nextAll().appendTo($('<ul>').insertAfter('ul:first'));
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/RhMj9/5/

Comment: Seem to leave (or produce) and empty `<ul></ul>` at the end of the other lists.

Comment: @j08691 forgot to delete that empty ul from the markup... http://jsfiddle.net/RhMj9/5/

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than 2 `ul` to do, you can use this code :

```
$('li').unwrap()
$('.text').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.text').addBack().wrapAll('<ul>')
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HBXNk/