# jQuery split long ul list in smaller lists with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists) is working well with ul to li.

This is my code :

```
    <div id="submenu-last" class="popover">
        <div class="popover-content">
            <div class="listCol">
                <ul id="bigList">
                    <% _.each(depList.getAll(),function(dep){ %>
                        <li><a href="#"><%=dep.Name%></a></li>
                    <% }); %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function(){
          var $bigList = $('#bigList'), group;
          while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(20)').remove()).length){
            $('<div class="listCol"><ul>').append(group).appendTo($('.popover-content'));
          }
   });
```

This is the result : 
[image]

What I expected :

```
 <div class="popover-content">
    <div class="listCol">
    <ul>
        <li>Cate1</li>
        <li>Cate2</li>
        ................
    </ul>
  </div>    
  <div class="listCol">
    <ul>
        <li>cate11</li>
        <li>cate12</li>
        ................
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: how is your code working cause `$('<div class="listCol"><ul>')` is not valid selector.Can you provide a fiddle.

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vLTJs/2/

Answer (score 1):

Saurabh is correct, `<div class="listCol"><ul>` is not a valid selector.

Try replacing that bit with:

<del>`$('<div class="listCol">').append('<ul>')`</del>

```
var $listCol = $('<div class="listCol">').appendTo('.popover-content');
$('<ul>').append(group).appendTo($listCol);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/E5Vu9/2/)

Comment: but his problem remains as the `<li>` are added after `<ul>`, it should be inside `<ul>`.

Comment: @Saurabh You're right, I didn't notice that. Fixed now. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/E5Vu9/2/

Comment: I have one problem with it, the default list is stay in every new list. It is not clear even I hover the other li.

Comment: @Domo Could you rephrase that?

Comment: I meant, when I hover on the 2nd 3rd 4th..... `ul`, `'<div class="listCol"><ul><li>..</li></ul>` of the first `ul` still appended.

Comment: @Domo Well, each group of `li` tags is inside a `ul` tag which is inside a `div.listCol` tag. Isn't that what you wanted? You can remove the empty `bigList` with `$bigList.remove();`

Comment: All the contents in the first `ul` are appended to the other `ul` dear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46216/discussion-between-tewathia-and-domo)