# Select first/last half of a group of spans

Tags: jquery

I have this table-like structure in my code. Is there a pretty way to select the first 'half' of the spans contained within the div?

```
<div> 
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I could do the typical div - children, then count and divide by two. But I was wondering if there was a selector based on a child interval position. Like .find("span[0-4]")

Comment: Please do try something or post what you've already tried.

Comment: There are many pretty and ugly ways. Which one have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery split long ul list in smaller lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists)

Comment: I explained a little bit more thorough what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`.slice()` method](https://api.jquery.com/slice/). Retrieve the total number of `span` elements by accessing the `.length` property, and then divide that in half:

```js
var $el = $('div span');
$el.slice(0, Math.ceil($el.length / 2)).addClass('half');
```

```css
div span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
}
.half {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

In order to access the last half, use either of the following instead:

```
$el.slice(Math.ceil($el.length / 2), $el.length)
```

```
$el.slice(-Math.ceil($el.length / 2))
```