# how to replace li with new ul from many li by jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery

my code like,

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
    <li id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want this like below:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
    <li id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it always 3 li elements? What have you tried?

Comment: You want to add only 3 `li` to `ul`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery split long ul list in smaller lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644668/jquery-split-long-ul-list-in-smaller-lists)

Comment: this question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var lis = $("ul > li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=3) {
  lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<ul></li>");
}
$("ul > ul").unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvyog7fb/)**

Comment: @user2240424: glad it helps ... don't forget to accept answer :)